# Applying two Vertex shaders on two models with the same pixel shader

Tags: directx, directx11, hlsl

I want to apply two HLSL vertex shaders on two different models but with the same pixel shader. What I've done is wrong but I don't know how I can use both vertex shaders with one pixel shader (and I don't know if it is possible to do such a thing or not). The reason for doing so is this:

[image]

What I have here is 2 boxes which one of them is inside of another. As you can see the smaller box can receive light which is opposite of the bigger box. The reason is because of the normal vector of the bigger box. I want to negative the normal for bigger box.
By the way, this is my code which is wrong and doesn't compile but I want to know the reason since I am junior in CG programming.

This is my init scene method:

```
bool InitScene()
{
    //Compile Shaders from shader file
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0, 0);
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects2.fx", 0, 0, "VS2", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Buffer2, 0, 0);
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0, 0);

//Create the Shader Objects
hr = d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
hr = d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer2->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer2->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS2);
hr = d3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

//Set Vertex and Pixel Shaders
d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader(VS2, 0, 0);
d3d11DevCon->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);


light.pos = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
light.range = 100.0f;
light.att = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.05f, 0.0f);
light.ambient = XMFLOAT4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
light.diffuse = XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
///////////////**************new**************////////////////////
//Create the vertex buffer
Vertex v[] =
{
    // Front Face
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),

    // Back Face
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),

    // Top Face
    Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),

    // Bottom Face
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),

    // Left Face
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),

    // Right Face
    Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
};

DWORD indices[] = {
    // Front Face
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,

    // Back Face
    4, 5, 6,
    4, 6, 7,

    // Top Face
    8, 9, 10,
    8, 10, 11,

    // Bottom Face
    12, 13, 14,
    12, 14, 15,

    // Left Face
    16, 17, 18,
    16, 18, 19,

    // Right Face
    20, 21, 22,
    20, 22, 23
};



D3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&indexBufferDesc, sizeof(indexBufferDesc));

indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * 12 * 3;
indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;

iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &iinitData, &squareIndexBuffer);

d3d11DevCon->IASetIndexBuffer(squareIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);


D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));

vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 24;
vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
///////////////**************new**************////////////////////

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData;

ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferData, sizeof(vertexBufferData));
vertexBufferData.pSysMem = v;
hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexBufferData, &squareVertBuffer);

//Create the Input Layout
hr = d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(),
    VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout);

//Create the Input Layout
hr = d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, VS_Buffer2->GetBufferPointer(),
    VS_Buffer2->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout);


//Set the Input Layout
d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout);

//Set Primitive Topology
d3d11DevCon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

//Create the Viewport
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
viewport.Width = Width;
viewport.Height = Height;

//depth
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

//Set the Viewport
d3d11DevCon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

//Create the buffer to send to the cbuffer in effect file
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbbd;
ZeroMemory(&cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerObject);
cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;

hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&cbbd, NULL, &cbPerObjectBuffer);

ZeroMemory(&cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerFrame);
cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;

hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&cbbd, NULL, &cbPerFrameBuffer);

//Camera information
camPosition = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 3.0f, -8.0f, 0.0f);
camTarget = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
camUp = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

//Set the View matrix
camView = XMMatrixLookAtLH(camPosition, camTarget, camUp);

//Set the Projection matrix
camProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.4f*3.14f, (float)Width / Height, screenNear, screenFar);

hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(d3d11Device, L"texture.jpg",
    NULL, NULL, &CubesTexture, NULL);


// Describe the Sample State
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampDesc;
ZeroMemory(&sampDesc, sizeof(sampDesc));
sampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
sampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
sampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
sampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

//Create the Sample State
hr = d3d11Device->CreateSamplerState(&sampDesc, &CubesTexSamplerState);

//avoid backface culling
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rastDesc;
ZeroMemory(&rastDesc, sizeof(D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC));
rastDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
rastDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
//  rastDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
d3d11Device->CreateRasterizerState(&rastDesc, &noCull);
d3d11DevCon->RSSetState(noCull);


return true;
}
```

and the draw method:

```
void DrawScene()
{
//Clear our backbuffer
float bgColor[4] = { (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) };
d3d11DevCon->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, bgColor);

//Refresh the Depth/Stencil view
d3d11DevCon->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

//set light
constbuffPerFrame.light = light;
d3d11DevCon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerFrameBuffer, 0, NULL, &constbuffPerFrame, 0, 0);
d3d11DevCon->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerFrameBuffer);

//Set the default blend state (no blending) for opaque objects
//d3d11DevCon->OMSetBlendState(0, 0, 0xffffffff);

//Reset Vertex and Pixel Shaders
d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
//d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader(VS2, 0, 0);
d3d11DevCon->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);


//Set our Render Target
d3d11DevCon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTargetView, depthStencilView);

//Set the default blend state (no blending) for opaque objects
d3d11DevCon->OMSetBlendState(0, 0, 0xffffffff);

//Set the cubes index buffer
d3d11DevCon->IASetIndexBuffer(squareIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

//Set the cubes vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
UINT offset = 0;
d3d11DevCon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &squareVertBuffer, &stride, &offset);

//Create the Input Layout
hr = d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(),
    VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout);


//Set the Input Layout
d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout);

//Set the WVP matrix and send it to the constant buffer in effect file
WVP = cube1World * camView * camProjection;
cbPerObj.World = XMMatrixTranspose(cube1World);
cbPerObj.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
d3d11DevCon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerObjectBuffer, 0, NULL, &cbPerObj, 0, 0);
d3d11DevCon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerObjectBuffer);

d3d11DevCon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &CubesTexture);
d3d11DevCon->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &CubesTexSamplerState);


//Draw the first cube
//d3d11DevCon->RSSetState(NULL);
d3d11DevCon->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);
//d3d11DevCon->RSSetState(noCull);



WVP = cube2World * camView * camProjection;
cbPerObj.World = XMMatrixTranspose(cube2World);
cbPerObj.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
d3d11DevCon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerObjectBuffer, 0, NULL, &cbPerObj, 0, 0);
d3d11DevCon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerObjectBuffer);

d3d11DevCon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &CubesTexture);
d3d11DevCon->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &CubesTexSamplerState);

//Draw the second cube
d3d11DevCon->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);

//Present the backbuffer to the screen
SwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: my problem is solved by using constant buffers. but i'm interested to know how can i use 2 vertex buffers with one index buffer in this example

Comment: I think that you don't use two vertex shaders to draw two objects and doing this all 'at once' - you just draw first object using first vertex shader and second object with 2nd vertex shader, right?